# (Making Excel Read) Hide/Show rows via Key Phrases

Tags: excel, vba, find, match, partial

Currently I get given 2 worksheets a day both with around 10,000 entries on each sheet in a single column. I have to use the find tool to match against the column in each sheet that contains a string of text. In total there are 11 phases I currently have to check for.

I would like to create a bit a code that would check inside each cell in the selected column for a match against the key phases.

I was thinking some kind of Loop and have each phase as a Variable that then loops and checks against the cell for a partial match. (No idea how to do the partial match) If no match is found out of any of the variants/variables the row is hidden.

As the phrases are computer generated its pointing out the partial match would always be the exact phase inside a sentence. 
Var1 = "client confirmed order" 
Cell B1 value =  "On 26/02/2009 client confirmed order of 8 boxes."

If anyone has any tutorials or links that might cover doing something similar I would be very grateful. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula to flag matches (example below), then filter the list to hide the zeros:

[image]